# JS/ Jquery - How to remove data-attributes in combination with adding/removing class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a class from a div and simultaneously add a class. It works fine if I dont have any data attributes attached to same div (I doubt its generally about data-attributes but guess its about the ones I have as they are used to produce effects).

Since removing/adding class doesnt work along with having data-attributes, I had the idea to remove data-attributes first, then remove/add class. The removal of the d. attr. works but then still I cannot remove/add a class. 
(To clarify why I dont just remove data.attr. from the html: I want add/remove a class for touch devices, where I dont need the data.attr., but need to keep them for other devices.)

I couldnt really find any solution..Any ideas?Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="welcomeFrame" class='frame2 frame' data-0='transform: scale(1.0,1.0);' data-150p='transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);opacity: 1;' data-200p='opacity: 0; transform: scale(6, 6);'>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById("welcomeFrame")
el.removeAttribute("data-0");
el.removeAttribute("data-150p");
el.removeAttribute("data-200p");
$("#welcomeFrame").removeClass("frame2").addClass("newFrame");
```

Comment: Adding and removing class strings from a node really has nothing at all to do with data attributes.

Comment: `Since removing/adding class doesnt work along with having data-attributes,` That's false. The two are not related. You have another issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about `data-` attributes that conflicts with the adding and removing of classes.

Your code, however jumps back and forth between JQuery syntax and vanilla JavaScript, I would just pick one and stick with it. For something simple like this, I personally don't think JQuery is needed.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("welcomeFrame");

el.removeAttribute("data-0");
el.removeAttribute("data-150p");
el.removeAttribute("data-200p");
el.classList.remove("frame2");
el.classList.add("newFrame");

// This shows that everything got removed/added as it should have:
console.log(el);
```

```css
frame2 { background-color:green; border:1px solid red; } /* This is the default */
.newFrame { background-color:yellow; }                   /* And, this is applied later by code */
```

```html
<div id="welcomeFrame" class='frame2 frame' 
     data-0='transform: scale(1.0,1.0);' 
     data-150p='transform: scale(1.3, 1.3);opacity: 1;' 
     data-200p='opacity: 0; transform: scale(6, 6);'>
     TEST
</div>
```